# Does the GDPR/data protection act contain any anti-reprisal provisions?

Tags: england-and-wales, gdpr, data-protection-act

The Information Commissioner's Office [ICO](https://ico.org.uk/) advisers state that one “shouldn't” be treated any directly or less favourably as a result of exercising one’s rights under the legislation. What legal provision backs this?

Does some section of the data protection act cover the issue? Or some broader principle under common law that states where the legislature grants a right or remedy to a person and they are spited or punished for exercising it then this is somehow seen in the eyes of the law as intrinsically wrong?

Comment: Who or what is ICO?

Comment: In UK Information Commissioners Office https://ico.org.uk/ "The ICO is the UK's independent body set up to uphold information rights.'

Comment: It would be helpful to quote or link to specific words used by the ICO

Comment: The title references anti-reprisal provisions, whereas the question is about being treated less favourably.  I have answered according to the latter

Comment: @alexg I’d agree, but they were spoken on a phone call and not written down.

Comment: @Rick I’m sorry but I’m not sure I can see a difference between those. Isn’t being treated less favourable in response to something the same thing as a reprisal?

Comment: It depends on one's definition of "reprisal".  Not treating someone fairly because they are a pain in the neck, or because of their protected characteristics, might fit.  But not being fair because of laziness, incompetence or lack of knowledge might not.